# How do I read all the contents of a HTML file inside of my jar and store it in a string

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have an HTML file under a directory in my JAR file under pages/newTab.html, and in Eclipse it obviously is in res/pages/newTab.html. My goal here is to read the contents of the whole HTML file and store it in a String.

I have tried multiple ways to get the file as a resource, then read it with a BufferedReader, it works in Eclipse, but not in the Runnable JAR. This is normally how I get the file as a resource, this works in Eclipse, but not in the Runnable JAR.

```
getClass().getResource("/pages/" + url.substring(7))
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/pages/" + url.substring(7)).toURI());
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
    stringBuffer.append("\n");
}
fileReader.close();

jep.setContentType("text/html");
jep.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
```

jep is the JEditorPane we are printing the text to.

EDIT: I do get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical` when Running the Runnable JAR with `File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/pages/" + url.substring(7)).toURI());`

Comment: Do you get an error? have you tried debuging or printing to check the value of `getClass().getResource("/pages/" + url.substring(7)).toURI()`?

Comment: Yes, I did, it prints the location of the HTML file.

Comment: So it has the correct path but if fails to read the file without any error?

Comment: It works fine in Eclipse like it is intended, but doesn't work in the Runnable JAR when exported.

Comment: Yes you already written that in your question, my questions regarding printing and any errors concerns when you run the exported jar.

Comment: I do get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical` when Running the Runnable JAR with `File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/pages/" + url.substring(7)).toURI());`

Comment: A resource in a jar file is NOT a file. A file lives on the file system, not inside a jar file. Use Class.getResourceAsStream() to read the resource. Not a File, not a FileInputStream, not a FileReader, since you do NOT have a file.

Answer (score -1):

Save the html outside the jar, this is what you can do with configuration files and other stuff like that. Create a folder for the application and store the executable jar and html inside.

```
  - application\ 
  ------- executable.jar
  ------- htmlFile.html
```

now do something like this:

```
    try {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("htmlFile.html"))));
        String content = "";
        for (String line : lines) {
              content += line + "\n";
        }
        jep.setContentType("text/html");
        jep.setText(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```